# water pressure in the oceans or great lakes

Tags: energy, pressure

Is there a way to create energy from water depth pressure? Convert the pressure to any type of energy?  Does there need to be movement? Can someone comment on this process?  Thanks

Comment: One does not simply *create* energy.

Answer (score 2):

[Hydroelectricity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydroelectricity), used all over the world, creates energy from the pressure of water.  Having made electricity, you can convert it to other kinds of energy.  There does need to be motion-energy is force times distance.  Just a static force does not give you energy.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to create energy from water depth pressure?

Yes, but you need the water to be able to flow to a lower pressure region.  So for example, hydroelectric power could be generated by run a pipe underground from the Mediterranean Sea (which is at sea level) to the Dead Sea which is well below sea level.